# Testing JavaFX Multitouch

Tags: java, testing, touch, javafx, multi-touch

I Have to test the GUI of an JavaFX Application which contains various Multitouch Events like rotate and zoom. But I can't find a testframework for simulating these Inputs. The only TestFramework that I could find for JavaFX is TestFX but that only uses the awt.Robot for Input, so I cant test touch events.

My Next idea to do this was with MultiTouchVista with that I have multiple mouse support(one mouse per finger) and I really able to get the Multitouch-events with it. But I cant automate 2 mice via Java.

Does anyone have ideas how I could automate/simulate touch events?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JavaFX with its TestFX does support different robots than only awt.robot. Check out this:

https://ustesis.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/headless-ui-testing-with-testfx-and-javafx-8/